# Need some assistance in writing this insert into query, what's an effective way to do it?

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql

I am putting together a recipe app but this time instead of the MEAN stack I am using PostgreSQL as the database. Everything goes well until its time for me to write the INSERT INTO and its all downhill from there, I have written this code several different ways and these are the errors I have received:

```
Server Stareted On Port 3000
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

error: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
```

tried something else and got:

```
Server Stareted On Port 3000
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

error: syntax error at or near "WHERE"
```

The above was from when I thought it woud work by adding where id =

```
Server Stareted On Port 3000
error running query { [error: there is no parameter $1]
  name: 'error',
  length: 87,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42P02',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '59',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'parse_expr.c',
  line: '824',
  routine: 'transformParamRef' }
```

Tried yet something else and got:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

error: INSERT has more expressions than target columns
```

I am at a loss as to what is going on or how to rearrange my code, I mean I thought it was as straightforward as something is missing with the primary id, but after trying all of the above I am spent quite frankly, don't know where to go from here and yes I have even looked at other posts here.

Here is the code for views/app.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    cons = require('consolidate'),
    dust = require('dustjs-helpers'),
    pg = require('pg'),
    app = express();

// create a config to configure both pooling behavior
// and client options
// note: all config is optional and the environment variables
// will be read if the config is not present
var config = {
  user: 'aleatoire', //env var: PGUSER
  database: 'recipebookdb', //env var: PGDATABASE
  password: '', //env var: PGPASSWORD
  port: 5432, //env var: PGPORT
  max: 10, // max number of clients in the pool
  idleTimeoutMillis: 30000, // how long a client is allowed to remain idle before being closed
};


//this initializes a connection pool
//it will keep idle connections open for 30 seconds
//and set a limit of maximum 10 idle clients
var pool = new pg.Pool(config);


// Assign Dust Engine To .dust Files
app.engine('dust', cons.dust);

// Set Default Ext .dust
app.set('view engine', 'dust');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

// Set Public Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    // to run a query we can acquire a client from the pool,
    // run a query on the client, and then return the client to the pool
    pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
      if(err) {
        return console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);
      }
      client.query('SELECT * FROM recipes', function(err, result) {

        if(err) {
          return console.error('error running query', err);
        }
        res.render('index', {recipes: result.rows});
        //call `done()` to release the client back to the pool
        done();

      });
    });

});

app.post('/add', function(req, res){
    // to run a query we can acquire a client from the pool,
    // run a query on the client, and then return the client to the pool
    pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
      if(err) {
        return console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);
      }
      client.query('INSERT INTO recipes(name, ingredients, directions) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4)', [req.body.name, req.body.ingredients, 
        req.body.directions]);

        done();
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});

// Server
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server Stareted On Port 3000');
});
```

Here is package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "recipebook",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A recipe web app with Nodejs and PostgreSQL",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Daniel Cortes",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "consolidate": "*",
    "dust": "*",
    "dustjs-helpers": "*",
    "dustjs-linkedin": "*",
    "express": "*",
    "pg": "*"
  }
}
```

Here is views/layout.dust:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>RecipeBook</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel ="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-7">
                    {+body /}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is views/index.dust:

```
{>"layout" /}

{<body}
    <button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formModal">
        Add Recipe
    </button>

    <br />

    {#recipes}
        <div class="well">
            <h4>{name} 
            <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" href="#recipe_{id}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="recipe_{id}">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button></h4>

            <div class="collapse" id="recipe_{id}">
              <br />
              <br />
              <p><strong>Ingredients: </strong>{ingredients}</p>
              <p><strong>Directions: </strong>{directions}</p>
              <br />
              <hr />
              <button class="btn btn-default edit-recipe">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </button>
              <button class="btn btn-danger delete-recipe">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    {/recipes}

    <!-- Add Form Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="formModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="formModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form method="post" action="/add">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Recipe</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Recipe Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Ingredients</label>
                    <textarea name="ingredients" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Directions</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="directions"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
              </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
{/body}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per code given, table structure seems like

```
CREATE TABLE public.recipes(
id integer NOT NULL, --(Actually NOT NULL is not required here, as it is Primary key)
name character(255), 
ingredients text, 
directions text, 
CONSTRAINT recipes_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

here `id` is primary key and you want it to be auto increment.

There are 2 ways to achieve this

1) Change id data type from `integer` to `SERIAL`

```
CREATE TABLE public.recipes(
id serial,
name character varying(255), 
ingredients text, 
directions text, 
CONSTRAINT recipes_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

You can call insert with 3 parameters.

```
INSERT INTO recipes(name, ingredients, directions) VALUES($1, $2, $3)', [req.body.name, req.body.ingredients, 
        req.body.directions]);
```

2) Use a `sequence`

In your case `SERIAL` will be good.

Change the data type of `id` column and hope it will works.

Answer (score 0):

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

error: INSERT has more expressions than target columns
```

Is from providing more arguments then columns specified:

`'INSERT INTO recipes(name, ingredients, directions) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4)', [req.body.name, req.body.ingredients, 
        req.body.directions]);`

Only 3 parameters are being provided:

`INSERT INTO recipes(name, ingredients, directions) VALUES($1, $2, $3)`

---

```
Server Stareted On Port 3000
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

error: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
```

Is the id the primary key? Should the id be null? Should it be Unique? If it is the primary key and should be unique then db's provide an AUTO INCREMENT column on primary key, so you don't have to worry about inserting a value for it.

---

These issue are completely independent from node, so it might be more focused to address them without having to look through JS code.  Any basic SQL tutorial should address all the errors that you have encountered.

Comment: So the idea in me writing this: [req.body.name, req.body.ingredients, 
    req.body.directions]); is to replace these placeholders here: VALUES($1, $2, $3)',. This is what I had when I got the "null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint". This is how I created the table: CREATE TABLE public.recipes(id integer NOT NULL, name character(255), ingredients text, directions text, CONSTRAINT recipes_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)); So yes, the id is the primary key and yes it should auto increment, but then why am I getting this error message and my new recipe is not being added?

Comment: assuming mysql: you could `MODIFY COLUMN` to be auto increment, then you wouldn't have to provide a value for it

Comment: In postgresql I believe its ALTER COLUMN, but I have tried different variations of this: ALTER TABLE recipes ALTER COLUMN recipes_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT; and I keep getting this: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INT". This is frustrating because as you are helping me I am looking up documentation on postgresql.

Comment: `int(11)` is not valid. You either write `int` for a standard integer or `numeric(11)` for a precise-arithmetic number with 11 significant digits. The former is far more efficient and PK's are not involved in math anyway. The exact command would be `ALTER TABLE recipes ALTER recipes_id SERIAL`. PK's are by default `NOT NULL` so you don't have to specify that.

Comment: Thank you Paarth, I finally got around to getting back to working on this project and your answer worked for me. My app is able to add recipes successfully now.